# how to implement multiple if-and function into a sql query?

Tags: sql, case-when

These two tables below are in the same excel file, but in my database both of them are separated into two different tables.

The first table looks like this:

table1

```
a_actual      b_actual      c_actual      no
2020-04-21     null         2020-05-23    1
null          2020-04-22    2020-04-27    2
```

While the second table looks like this:

table2

```
a        30
b        40
c        100
```

Both tables are combined and operated with if-and function in excel to get each weight from table 2.

the if function in excel is:

```
=if(and(a_actual>0; a_actual<=now()); a; (if(and(b_actual>0; b_actual<= now()); b; (if(and(c_actual>0; c_actual<=now());c;0))))
```

Assuming that the current date is today: 2021-06-08, then the expected result:

```
no     weight
1       100
2       100
```

I need to implement this if-and function of excel into a sql query.

I supposed I can use case when, but I don't know exactly how to write the query properly.

How can I implement the if-and function into a sql query?

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: excel, postgresql and sql-server are 3 different things. tag only one which you looking for as syntax will be different in solution

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Your results are not consistent with the Excel formula.  Please explain the calculation of the results.